# Can we stop session reset if page reloads?

Tags: php, session, reset

I started a session and assigned a value and based on the value other function executes but the page reloads after first session and obviously session resets and the other page where I am calling this session the required value is not fetched.

So is there a way to stop session reset? Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't use PHP sessions.

If you tried stating a session in your custom-written code, it's not going to work as you'd hope.

There's a plugin which will enable all normal `session` use: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-native-php-sessions/

But, depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve, you may prefer to keep things clean/do it the WordPress way and use a `cookie` and store data in the database as `user_meta`.